# Mac Chrome crashes sometimes when animate left jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Hi guys im currently developing this [site](http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0088_MIO/demo/):

It's almost done but im having some problems when you click the "Eventos" div , sometimes the animation is slow and sometimes it crashes i dont know why.

Here's the part of my code that does the animation.

```
 case 'Eventos':
           if(cargado == true){
             if(banderapuntoventa == true){
                    $("#cuartimg").removeClass('forzadapv')
                    $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({"top": "1500px"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){
                        banderaeventos = true;
                        $("#eventosydemas").css({"margin-right": '97%', "right": '10px'})
                        $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({"left": "0"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){
                            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                            $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                            $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                            $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                            $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                        })
                    })
                    $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                    $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                    $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                    banderapuntoventa = false;


                }
                else{

                    banderaeventos = true;
                    $("#eventosydemas").css({"margin-right": '97%', "right": '10px'})
                    $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({"left": "0"}, 2000,function(){
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                            $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                            $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                            $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                            $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})

                })

                }
            }
            else{
                $(".dial").knob({
                    readOnly:true
                });

                iniloader(50);
                banderaeventos = true;

                    $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({"left": "0"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){
                        $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                        $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                        $("#header").css({"height": '100px', "background": 'none'})
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                        $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                    })

            }

          break;


case 'PuntosdeVenta':
           if(cargado == true){
              if(banderaeventos == true){

                    $("#cuartimg").removeClass('forzadapv')
                     $("#eventosydemas").animate({"margin-right": "0px","right":"0px"}, 1500)
                    $("#eventos").stop(true,false).animate({"left": "100%"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){

                        banderapuntoventa = true;
                        $("#cuartimg").addClass('forzadapv')
                        $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({"top": "0"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){
                            $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                            $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                            $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                            $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                        })

                    })
                    $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                    $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                    banderaeventos = false;

                }
                else if(banderascroll == false){
                    $(".hoverini").removeClass('focusmenu')
                    $("#cuartimg").addClass('forzadapv')
                    $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                    $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                    $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({"top": "0"}, 2000,function(){
                        $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                        $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                    })
                }
                else{

                    banderapuntoventa = true;
                    $("#cuartimg").addClass('forzadapv')
                    $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                    $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                    $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({"top": "0"}, 2000,function(){
                        $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                        $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                    })

                }
            }
            else{

                $(".dial").knob({
                    readOnly:true
                });

                iniloader();
                banderapuntoventa = true;
                    $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({"top": "0"}, 1500,"easeOutSine",function(){
                        $("#esctop,#escbot").stop(true,false).fadeOut(400)
                        $("#esctop2,#escbot2").stop(true,false).fadeIn(400)
                        $("#header").css({"height": '100px'})
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')
                        $("#puntosdeventadiv").stop(true,false).animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 1},function(){})
                    })

            }

          break;
```

Comment: This site is incredibly animation heavy. Each step of the animation requires that the entire page layout be redrawn. I'd highly suggest using CSS for this instead, as pepole who don't have fast computers are going to suffer.